# Ruby/Rails convert string to a class attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a class `Article`, such that:

```rb
class Article

  attr_accessor :title, :author

  def initialize(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author= author
  end

end
```

Also, variable `atrib` is a `String` containing the name of an attribute. How could I turn this string into a variable to use as a getter?

```rb
a = Article.new
atrib='title'
puts a.eval(atrib)     # <---- I want to do this
```

**EXTENDED**

Suppose I now have an `Array` of articles, and I want to sort them by title. Is there a way to do the compact version using `&` as in:

```rb
col = Article[0..10]
sorted_one = col.sort_by{|a| a.try('title') }   #This works
sorted_two = col.sort_by(&:try('title'))   #This does not work
```

Comment: have you tried `a.send(atrib.to_sym)`

Comment: @engineersmnky that indeed works, thanks!

Comment: `to_sym` is not actually required a string is acceptable as well so you could call `a.send(atrib)`

Comment: why not `a.title`.. ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I reduced it to a simple example. The tricky thing is that I've got the attribute name stored into a string.

Comment: is your class an `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either `send` or `instance_variable_get`:

```
a = Article.new 'Asdf', 'Coco'
a.pubic_send(:title) # (Recommended) Tries to call a public method named 'title'. Can raise NoMethodError
=> "Asdf"
# If at rails like your case:
a.try :title # Tries to call 'title' method, returns `nil` if the receiver is `nil` or it does not respond to method 'title'
=> "Asdf"
a.send(:title) # Same, but will work even if the method is private/protected
=> "Asdf"
a.instance_variable_get :@title # Looks for an instance variable, returns nil if one doesn't exist
=> "Asdf"
```

Shot answer to your extended question: no. The `&:symbol` shortcut for procs relies on `Symbol#to_proc` method. So to enable that behavior you'd need to redifine that method on the Symbol class:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc  
    ->(x) { x.instance_eval(self.to_s) }    
  end  
end

[1,2,3].map(&:"to_s.to_i * 10")
=> [10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Or `.try`, which would be a more graceful way.

Comment: @pduersteler great insight! only applying to Rails though

Comment: @nicooga Please see updated post, for a subquestion of the initial  question.

Comment: what is the difference of these three different methods?

Comment: @nicooga thanks for the answer to the extended part! I see why now

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord` instances have an [`attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) hash:

```
a = Article.new(title: 'foo')
#=> <#Article id: nil, title: "foo">

atrib = 'title'
a.attributes[atrib]
#=> "foo"
```

You can use [`order`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) to get sorted objects from your database:

```
Article.order('title').first(10)
#=> array of first 10 articles ordered by title
```